# Solr MoreLikeThis: Can I give Solr 5 document IDs and get more documents like these 5?

Tags: solr, lucene, morelikethis

I'm unclear on this point from the documentation. Is it possible to give Solr X document IDs and tell it that I want documents similar to those?

Example:

- The user is browsing 5 different articles
- I send Solr the IDs of these 5 articles so I can present the user other similar articles

I am not clear about sending the document IDs, nor whether MoreLikeThis can operate on multiple documents as in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try passing multiple Ids with the Query `q=id:(document_id1 OR document_id2 OR document_id3)` :-

e.g.

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select/?qt=mlt&q=id:(document_id1 OR document_id2 OR document_id3)&mlt.fl=[field1],[field2],[field3]&fl=id&rows=10
```

Comment: I tried this OR syntax, but I just get an error: Query parsing error: Cannot parse 'id:[1004401713626 OR 1000302912757]': Encountered " <RANGEIN_GOOP> "1000302912757 "" at line 1, column 21.
Was expecting:
    "]" ...

Comment: sorry it should probably be in the curve brackets. Edited the answer.

Comment: This still gives the results of first doc only!