# How to get full documents via MoreLikeThis search in solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, morelikethis

I´m quite new to the MoreLikeThis search in solr but i find one option is missing.
The wiki pages and google (and stack overflow) search says nothing about the document format of the returned value of a MLT-Search.
My aim is to get either all or at least a specified field-set in the returned documents, but it seams that one have no influence which fields are included in the similar documents. 
Of course one can do a query for each of the documents from the moreLikeThis result to get those field but i don´t like the idea to do multiple queries where just one could really be sufficient.

I would really appreciate if anybody does knows a way to influence the result format of the documents.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using the MoreLikeThis component, it uses the same fl parameter to determine the returned content as does the initial Search process.  So, for example, if the query parameters include fl=score,* (fl=score%2C%2A in an HTTP query), then every returned document and every similar document returns its score and all the stored fields.  fl=score,itemId would return just the score and itemId of every returned document and similar document.  In other words, you cannot control independently the returned document and similar document fields.

Comment: I did have a case where I needed independent control, so I had the first query return me just the ids of the similar documents.  I could then filter these and return the information I wanted with a second query, providing all of the ids in the query parameter.  (See the discussion <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029457/solr-morelikethis-can-i-give-solr-5-document-ids-and-get-more-documents-like-th?rq=1>)  So even in this case, one doesn't need multiple queries, just two queries.